# Is it okay to re-sign not yet expired java certificate?

Tags: java, security, certificate

Is it okay if I re-sign almost expired self-signed java certificate?

That is, I had self-signed certificate, I generated CSR from it:

```
keytool -certreq -file certreq.csr -keystore keyStore -alias certAlias
```

And then imported response from Thawte into it:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore keyStore -alias certAlias -file cert.p7b
```

The sign period expires in less than a month. Will it be correct to repeat the above procedure? Or should I create fresh self-signed certificate for it?

Comment: By 'above procedure', do you mean to get a signature from Thawte for the certificate again?

Comment: @Tichodroma - I planned to generate new CSR, send it to Thawte, get new .p7b, and import it again.

Comment: Sign it whenever you like, it's your certificate. Off topic though.

Comment: @EJP - but is it okay from technical point of view? Wouldn't doubly-signed certificate be an error?